# php session: session values cleared on return from twitter login

Tags: facebook, session, twitter, php

I have a script that sets some session values when the visitor hits the site (just visitor stats).

The user is then allowed to signup via twitter/facebook or via a "regular register" process.

Now when the user comes back from the twitter/facebook part of the login process the session values are cleared (but not unset).

The issue is that it only happens on one server (a clients server). On my own server and locally on my machine it's fine.

Is there a server/php.ini setting that may be causing some issues?

note: the facebook/twitter signin process re-directs to those sites as opposed to the "popup" window style of signing up - in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried Twitter Login myself. But, Facebook, yes! From your footnote it is clear that you are using the **PHP SDK** for facebook which is not a very good(read-> g*ood looking*) choice. On October 3rd, Fb has released an updated version of [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) that you can use for the login. That workflow is beautiful. User clicks on your "Login with Facebook" button and a small pop-up opens up with the fb url and user authorizes and the pop-up goes away and the user is back on your site. With your current model, user clicks on the button and goes to another domain and then is again redirected. Check out the login with facebook from Miniclip.com and you would know what I am talking about.
As for your problem, without a look at your code, I feel the problem lies in the fact that PHP Session variables do not work cross-domain.

> Picture this: user is on your site -> generates $_SESSION['id'] -> Now, redirected to Fb -> PHP $_SESSION is not going to work once they have left your domain -> -> you pull out your hair!!

Comment: Should not the session value remain (as it works like that on my own server) when the person returns to the site as the session between the client and server remains even if they leave the site (unless the session times out - which thinking about it could be the issue, but even then it should not clear the session but simply remove it)